# How do I send variants by email in python?

Tags: python, email, variant

How can I send variants by email using python? The email is sent but not with the variants. Here is the code:

```
\`import email.message import os import smtplib import sys

def restart_program(): python = sys.executable os.execl(python, python, \* sys.argv)

print('Enter the first element:') first_element = (input()) print('Enter the second element:') second_element = (input()) print('Enter the result:') result = (input())

def send_email(): email_body = """ \[ { production1: first_element production2: second_element result: result #I want that the variants: "first_element" "second_element" and "result" be send in the email as the user writes in the input } \] """ from_addr = 'CENSURED' to_addr = 'CENSURED' password = 'CENSURED'

msg = email.message.Message() msg.set_payload(email_body)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) server.starttls() server.login(from_addr, password) server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string()) server.quit()

print("It's correct?") print(first_element) print("+") print(second_element) print("=") print(result) print('Confirm') Confirm = (input()) if Confirm.lower() == "yes": print("Sending Email...") Send_email() print('Email sent!') restart_program() else: print("Try Again") restart_program()\`\`
```

I tried putting quotation marks in the variants and using strings:
`def send_email():   email_body = """   [   {   production1: %s %first_element   production2: %s %second_element   result: %s %result   }   ]   """`

(I'm a newbie in programation so I probably used it wrong)

but it dosent work, I want that the words the user writes in the input be writen in the email body insted of the name of the variants, for instance: if the user writes test in the input of the first_element, test(1) in the second_element and test(2) in the result, in the body be like this:
`[ { production1: test production2: test(1) result: test(2) } ]`

Comment: By "variant", do you actually mean "variable" ?

Comment: Also, please format your code properly.  lt looks a mess.

Comment: Yes I meant variable and sorry for the mess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to include variables in a string message, you have several options.

The easiest way is to format your message using F-strings:

```
message = f"Hello {name}, I am glad to meet you."
```

Because there is an `f` before the quote mark at the start of the string, any expressions enclosed in curly braces like `{name}` or `{x+y}` will be replaced with the string representation of the value of the expression.